# I want to detect in-app browser of slack using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, slack, inappbrowser

I'm making a mobile website using NextJS and sharing the site link on Slack.
When the link is clicked, it opens within the in-app browser of Slack. However, I would like it to open in an external browser.

So I use navigator.useragent to detect the current browser condition.
For example, if I open the link in kakaotalk, the useragent includes a "kakaotalk" paragraph, allowing me to identify that it's within the in-app browser of KakaoTalk.

However, when I open the link in Slack, then useragent don't includes a "slack" paragraph and there's no distinction between the in-app browser of Slack and an external browser.

How can I detect the in-app browser of slack?

My goal is to initially open my site within the in-app browser of Slack and then transition to an external browser.

Additionally, I used an Android phone, and I used Chrome as my browser

Comment: Detecting an in-app browser like Slack's can indeed be tricky because it might not always have a distinct user agent. There's no standard method to identify all in-app browsers due to the variety of user agent strings that can be used by different apps, as far as I know.